# Creating a table in PHP within current function

Tags: php, glob

I am really struggling with some PHP. I have Googled and asked everyone I know before troubling you fine people!

I have cribbed together the below to display the latest 20 files as links from a folder.

The only problem I have is the output is a single string. I really want to put it in a table.

Each time I try it just dumps everything in each field, so I guess there is some clever looping that I need!

Any ideas? Here is my code:

```
<?php
$dir = "./PDF";
chdir($dir );
$show = 20;

$files = glob( '*.{pdf}', GLOB_BRACE );
usort( $files, create_function('$b, $a', 'return filemtime( $a ) - filemtime( $b );') );

for ( $i = 0; $i < $show; ++$i )
echo '<a href="./PDF/', $file = $files[$i], '" target="_blank">', $file, '</a> - ', date( 'D, M d, Y', filemtime($file) ), ' - ',filesize($file),'kb;<br /><br/>', "\n";
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
<?php
$dir = "./PDF";
chdir($dir );
$show = 20;

$files = glob( '*.{pdf}', GLOB_BRACE );
usort( $files, create_function('$b, $a', 'return filemtime( $a ) - filemtime( $b );') );

echo '<table>';
for ( $i = 0; $i < $show; ++$i ) {
    $file = $files[$i];
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td><a href="./PDF/'. $file .'" target="_blank">'. $file .'</a></td>';
    echo '<td>'.date( 'D, M d, Y', filemtime($file) ). '</td>';
    echo '<td>'. filesize($file) .'kb</td>';
    echo '</tr>';
}
echo '</table>';
```

Comment: YES!!! This is exactly what i needed to happen. I tried so many times and just got a blank page. I must have missed something in my set up. I spent the entire weekend trying to do this! Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

`foreach` might make this easier for you, 
But it looks like your problem is:

1). Use `.` not `,` to concatenate.

2). put "\n" at the end for "new line"

```
foreach($files as $file){

    echo '<tr><td><a href="./PDF/'.$file.'" target="_blank">'.$file.'</a></td><td>'., date( 'D, M d, Y', filemtime($file) ).'</td> <!--etc -->'."\n";//double quotes around "\n"  
 // for your 20 limit, you could:
i++; if(i>=20){break;}
```

//  but you could just stick with the for loop, and take the assignments out. 
      }

Comment: Thank you so much for your response. I really appreciate it.